# Custom Android service not found despite proper permissions and queries with SDK 33

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

In [this project](https://github.com/victorpaleologue/pddl-planning-android/tree/service_not_found), I provide two example apps:

- a "service app" providing a service like this:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.softbankrobotics.pddlplanning.example.service">
...
  <permission
      android:name="com.softbankrobotics.planning.SEARCH_PLANS"
      android:protectionLevel="normal" />

  <application ...>
    ...
    <service
        android:name=".ExamplePDDLPlannerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.softbankrobotics.planning.SEARCH_PLANS">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.softbankrobotics.planning.action.SEARCH_PLANS_FROM_PDDL" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

The service interface is defined with [this `.aidl`](https://github.com/victorpaleologue/pddl-planning-android/blob/service_not_found/pddl-planning/src/main/aidl/com/softbankrobotics/pddlplanning/IPDDLPlannerService.aidl) file. It shows one method accepting two strings, and returning a list of parcelable objects.

- a "client app", configured to use the service like this:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="com.softbankrobotics.planning.SEARCH_PLANS" />
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.softbankrobotics.pddlplanning.example.service" />
    <intent>
        <action android:name="com.softbankrobotics.planning.action.SEARCH_PLANS_FROM_PDDL" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

... and it binds the service this way, after permissions were successfully checked:

```kotlin
val plannerServiceIntent = Intent(IPDDLPlannerService.ACTION_SEARCH_PLANS_FROM_PDDL)
plannerServiceIntent.`package` = "com.softbankrobotics.pddlplanning.example.service"
val foundService = context.bindService(plannerServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
if (!foundService) {
    context.unbindService(serviceConnection)
    throw RemoteException("Planner service was not found")
}
```

(this piece of code was re-assembled, it is more spread around in the repository)

Despite exporting the service, declaring and checking permissions, ensuring package visibility for the client... My call to `bindService` returns `false`, and [the logs](https://pastebin.com/VzWkNdPG) confirm the service was not found.
Whereas [`dumpsys` shows the service is here](https://pastebin.com/LKp04K8y).

What did I do wrong?

Note that I compile using the Android SDK version 33, and I used to know how to do this with older Android SDK versions.

To reproduce the issue:

- build the APKs, install them
- run the Planning Client app (`ExampleClientActivity` from the `client-app-example` module)

Comment: Are you sure that `IPDDLPlannerService.ACTION_SEARCH_PLANS_FROM_PDDL` is `"com.softbankrobotics.planning.action.SEARCH_PLANS_FROM_PDDL"`? Does Logcat show anything useful at the point of your failed binding attempt?

Comment: Yes, see https://github.com/victorpaleologue/pddl-planning-android/blob/9724206c6b3ce5007cafa1412836d7566b278447/pddl-planning/src/main/aidl/com/softbankrobotics/pddlplanning/IPDDLPlannerService.aidl#L12
I'm adding a link to the logs of a run. It behaves as if the service did not exist.

Comment: @VictorPaléologue Are you getting the same error even when you declare the service in the manifest xml file using the whole package name like <service android:name="com.softbankrobotics.pddlplanning.example.service.ExamplePDDLPlannerService" instead of <service android:name=".ExamplePDDLPlannerService" in the service app? After you made the change make sure you delete both service and client apks from the device and install the service app first before installing the client-app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have just tried it out, and that did not change a thing. I clearly uninstalled the apps, re-installed them in the right order, and disabled the automatic cancellation of permission for these apps.

Comment: When you create the `Intent` to bind to the `Service`, set the component (package and class name) and see if that helps.

Comment: That does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!
The [`applicationId` in the `build.gradle`](https://github.com/victorpaleologue/pddl-planning-android/blob/service_not_found/service-app-example/build.gradle#L11) differed from [the package name in the manifest](https://github.com/victorpaleologue/pddl-planning-android/blob/service_not_found/service-app-example/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L3).